AspNetCore Minimal API How Catching Error Binding Parameters?
I use .NET 8 and I have minimal API in ApsNetCore. I have this GET method with param bindings using StronglyTypedId:
internal static async Task<Results<Ok<PaginatedList<TestResultDto>>, BadRequest<string>, NotFound>> Handle(
    [AsParameters] GetTestResultsRequest request,
    IValidator<GetTestResultsRequest> validator)
{
    ..some code..
}

and
public record GetTestResultsRequest(
    PatientProfileId? PatientProfileId,
    ...

where:
[StronglyTypedId]
public readonly partial struct PatientProfileId;

My problem is that when a client is sending a request with improper Guid:
https://localhost:7158/v1/test_results?PatientProfileId=df8537ab

I get a response as internal server error:
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-500-internal-server-error",
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}

Clearly it is a Client error instead 4xx, so how can I catch these type of errors and change the response error?
thanks

why do you think it's a client error?

if the param is not a Guid then it is a Client error. What else?

I think what browsermator concerned is how a client report 500 error, he might think this shall be a server error. Anyway, I think this document about how to handle errors in minimal API shall be helpful here.

thanks, I solved by creating a global exception handler and parsing the error type. If it is client type error then I use the 4xx code.
